# How to implement Wormhole pattern with AspectJ (cflow)

Tags: java, aspectj

I am trying to develop a simple wormhole using AspectJ and cflow.

I have two value objects Person and Account as shown below

**ACCOUNT**

```
public class Account {

    private final String sortCode;
    private final String accountNumber;
    private final int balance;

    public Account(String sortCode, String accountNumber, int balance) {
        this.sortCode = sortCode;
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.balance = balance;
    }

    public String getSortCode() {
        return sortCode;
    }

    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public int getBalance() {
        return balance;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Account{" +
                "sortCode='" + sortCode + '\'' +
                ", accountNumber='" + accountNumber + '\'' +
                ", balance=" + balance +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**PERSON**

```
public class Person {

    private final String name;
    private final String address;
    private final int age;

    public Person(String name, String address, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", address='" + address + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And three "Layers"

**Layer A**

```
public class Layer_A {

    public void doSomeLevelAprocess(Person person){

        System.out.println("doSomeLevelAprocess person " + person);
        new Layer_B().doSomeLevelBprocess();

    }
}
```

**Layer B**

```
public class Layer_B {

    public void doSomeLevelBprocess(){

        System.out.println("doSomeLevelBprocess");
        new Layer_C().doSomeLevelCprocess(new Account("123456", "87654321", 1001));

    }
}
```

**Layer C**

```
public class Layer_C {

    public void doSomeLevelCprocess(Account account){

        System.out.println("doSomeLevelCprocess " );

    }
}
```

I would like to have the `Person` object thats passed to `Layer_A` method
`doSomeLevelAprocess` made available at `Layer_C` method `doSomeLevelCprocess`

Is this possible?

my aspect looks like  this a

```
public aspect WormWhole {

    pointcut callerSpace(Person person): execution(* Layer_A.*(..)) && this(person);

    pointcut calleeSpace(Account account): this(account) && execution(public * Layer_C.*(..));

    pointcut wormhole(Person person, Account account):
            cflow(callerSpace(person)) && calleeSpace(account);

    before(Person person, Account account):
            wormhole(person, account){ **//WHAT DO I DO HERE?????** }
}
```

Have I selected pointcuts callerSpace and calleeSpace correctly?

What logic is required in

```
before(Person person, Account account):
                wormhole(person, account){ **//WHAT DO I DO HERE?????** }
```

**UPDATE**

The "Possible Duplicate" question does not actually illustrate HOW to achieve a wormhole, it simply shows a "template" for an AspectJ wormhole. In addition question answer referred to doesnt attempt to pass context through multiple layers, which is the entire point of a wormhole.

**UPDATE**

When i change the advice to this:-

```
public aspect WormWhole {

    pointcut callerSpace(Person person): execution(* Layer_A.*(..)) && this(person);

    pointcut calleeSpace(Account account): this(account) && execution(public * Layer_C.*(..));

    pointcut wormhole(Person person, Account account):
            cflow(callerSpace(person)) && calleeSpace(account);

    before(Person person, Account account):
            wormhole(person, account){
        System.out.println("Wormhole - " + person);
        System.out.println("Wormhole - " + account);


    }
}
```

I receive this output:-

```
doSomeLevelAprocess person Person{name='aaa', address='aaa', age=19}
doSomeLevelBprocess
doSomeLevelCprocess 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This proves my pointcuts are not correct (I believe), but why????

**UPDATE**

I have added in simple pointcut which works fine

```
public aspect WormWhole {

    pointcut callSayHello(): call(* Layer_A.*(..)) || call(* Layer_B.*(..)) || call(* Layer_C.*(..))  ;

    pointcut callerSpace(Person person): execution(* Layer_A.*(..)) && this(person);

    pointcut calleeSpace(Account account): this(account) && execution(public * Layer_C.*(..));

    pointcut wormhole(Person person, Account account):
            cflow(callerSpace(person)) && calleeSpace(account);

    before(Person person, Account account):
            wormhole(person, account){
        System.out.println("Wormhole - " + person);
        System.out.println("Wormhole - " + account);


    }

    after() : callSayHello()  {
        System.out.println("After call sayHello" + thisJoinPoint);
    }
}
```

Output from test execution

```
doSomeLevelAprocess person aaa
doSomeLevelBprocess
doSomeLevelCprocess account 87654321
After call sayHellocall(void Layer_C.doSomeLevelCprocess(Account))
After call sayHellocall(void Layer_B.doSomeLevelBprocess())
After call sayHellocall(void Layer_A.doSomeLevelAprocess(Person))

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am using CTW within `IntelliJ 14.1.14`, with `aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementing a wormhole pattern using AspectJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129562/implementing-a-wormhole-pattern-using-aspectj)

Comment: That question/answer(s) does not explain HOW to achieve the desired result. Also that questions example code does not have multiple layers to pass through

Comment: I am the one who answered the other question. I have not actually tried to run your code but at first glance the pointcuts look okay. As for your concern about the number of levels, it just does not matter - that is the whole point of the wormhole pattern. As for your question "what do I do here?" - well, it depends on you. Try printing the two objects, for instance. If you can print them you can also do anything else with them. It only depends on what you want to achieve. Whatever you do, basically you use the `Person` object in the execution context of the `Account` object - cool, isn't it?

Comment: @kriegaex thanks for your time, it is cool, i wish i could get it to work!!! :(

Comment: I can run your code when I get home tonight (Central European Time) earliest. Meanwhile a quick question, just so as to double-check: Do other (simpler) aspects run in your project? I just want to exclude compilation, deployment or load-time weaving problems. Do you use CTW or LTW?

Comment: @kriegaex thanks again for bothering with this, i have updated my question to show simple aspects do work OK. I have a strong feeling i have messed up my wormhole pointcuts:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you got something wrong with your pointcuts, which is why the AspectJ compiler shows this warning:

```
advice defined in Wormhole has not been applied [Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch]
```

The reason is simple: You are trying to bind your method arguments via `this()` instead of `args()`. This way both pointcuts cannot match because the `this` objects in the two execution contexts are instances of `Layer_A` and `Layer_C`, not `Person` and `Account`.

This little change fixes your wormhole pattern aspect:

```java
pointcut callerSpace(Person person) :
    execution(* Layer_A.*(..)) && args(person);

pointcut calleeSpace(Account account) : 
    execution(public * Layer_C.*(..)) && args(account);
```